# How nginx reload work ? why it is zero-downtime

Tags: nginx

refer to nginx official docs . the reload command of nginx is for reload of configuration files ，and during the progress , there's no downtime of the service .

i've learned that  it wait requests that already connected until it finished ,and stop accept any new request . the idea is cool , but how does it deal with the keep-live connections ? because those long-live connections won't close and there continuous request comes along .

Comment: Suppose, requests will be coming on the persistent connections, so what? After config changes are applied, the requests will be evaluated against the new logic (new routing rules or whatever changed in the config).

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Comment: @AlexeyTen, as I understand the question is how would it do in case of keepalive connections. What if I have a keepalive timeout as long as 10 minutes - would nginx hold outdated workers for that long? Did you check it?

Comment: Oh, I've missed part about keep-alive. Until recently old workers could live indefinitely long. In version 1.11.11 (a week ago) http://nginx.org/r/worker_shutdown_timeout directive was added. May be it will help.

Comment: wow nice option, thanks. upvoted the comment

Comment: does the reload include modification of SSL certificate?

Comment: @AlexeyTen What is the default value for `worker_shutdown_timeout` if not specified?

Comment: default value for `worker_shutdown_timeout` is 60s for nginx (not sure, got from google). and for ingress nginx it is 240s. But this does not apply to live-long connections like websockets according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821421/nginx-reload-ignores-worker-shutdown-timeout

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's the summary:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

> The master process first checks the syntax validity, then tries to
>   apply new configuration. If this succeeds, it starts new worker
>   processes, and sends messages to old worker processes requesting them
>   to shut down gracefully.

That means it would keep older processes handling unclosed connections while having new processes working according to the updated configuration.
From this perspective connections with keep-alive are no different from other unclosed connections.

In versions prior to 1.11.11 such "old" processes could hang indefinitely long (according to @Alexey, haven't checked it though), from 1.11.11 there’s a configuration setting controlling this
http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_shutdown_timeout

Comment: thank you. this is especially useful for when initiating nginx reload command to load a new configuration, and having open nginx streams. because nothing closes the streams, the original workers will hang indefinitely. using this directive, the nginx streams are also disconnected and the new nginx workers are started.

Comment: What is the default value for `worker_shutdown_timeout` if not specified?

Comment: @duct_tape_coder the default value is none, which means wait forever.