# nginx reload ignores worker_shutdown_timeout

Tags: nginx

Clients connect to my Nginx instance with the keep-alive of 15s. I set `worker_shutdown_timeout` to 30s, and server keep-alive to 90s.

When I send `-HUP` signal or using `Nginx -s reload` to my instance. It creates new workers and immediately shuts down old workers. This causes my clients to get 499 EOFs.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keepalive connections are closed immediately regardless of the `worker_shutdown_timeout` value, as clients are expected to re-open them as needed. The `worker_shutdown_timeout` applies to connections with actual requests being processed - these requests will be terminated when shutdown timeout expires.

If your clients cannot handle keepalive connection being closed by the server, probably there is room for improvement in the client code.

Comment: Can you please provide source of this fact you made? So does this clearly mean that nginx  will surely drop websocket connections when it reloads without any workaround for keeping the connections live.

Comment: @AyushTiwari, there are multiple facts in my answer, for sources please check nginx source code, nginx documentation, and relevant RFCs. Note though that websocket connections are not keepalive connections, and websocket connections are closed only if `worker_shutdown_timeout` is configured and expires.